# Differences between java.util.Calendar.MONTH and Oracle Databse MONTH function

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa

I'd like to select entities from my Oracle Database via JPA by making a query like this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(anOtherDate);

Query q = super.getEntityManager()
    .createQuery("select t from MyTable as t
                    where extract(month from t.myDate) = :month")
.setParameter("month", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

But the month number is different between Java and Oracle Database...

Is there a "cleaner" way to do this : `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)` ?

Comment: "extract" is not a valid JPQL function. "function" is how you call random SQL native functions

Comment: You could use a better date/time API: java.time in Java 8, or Joda Time...

Comment: `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1` is not a problem, and is as "clean" as it gets if you're using `Calendar`

Comment: Agreed with nos. What's unclean about the current solution? Its functionally and technically correct; Calendar returns a zero-based month so to get it in the range of the database, which is 1-based, you have to increment it by one.

Comment: What's unclean ? It's vendor specific and not standard JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're relying on native SQL anyway, why not extract the month from the DB's `sysdate` for comparison?

Comment: Sorry, my example is bad. Indeed, I don't use `cal.setTime(new Date());` but `cal.setTime(anOtherDate);`

Comment: @BnJ Ray doesn't means like that. You don't need to pass java date to sql server, instead db server's system date should be used in your query.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Ray answer, you should use db's system date like,

```
Query q = super.getEntityManager()
.createQuery("select t from MyTable as t
                where extract(month from t.myDate) = 
                   SQL('(SELECT extract(month from SYSDATE) FROM DUAL)')
            ");
```

Comment: Yes thanks but I want to select entities not for the current month but for any month.

Comment: @BnJ Calendar is `0` based for month. And note that you are retrieving the records with month only and not consider the year ???

Comment: 'SQL' is not a valid JPQL construct. Use createNativeQuery and use SQL direct if using that (or use JPA 2.1 'FUNCTION')

Comment: @NeilStockton See this link http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#SQL

Comment: @WundwinBorn I'm referring to JPA, not to vendor specifics that tie the user to a particular implementation; use stuff like that at your peril, particularly when there is a JPA standard way of doing it

Comment: @NeilStockton Pls suggest me if any other JPA vendor are using `extract()` function in SO post. Thanks !!!

Comment: I know of no other JPA provider that supports that vendor extension - the operative word being extension (i.e not part of the standard). As already said, JPA 2.1 allows a user to use standardised "function('extract', args)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59785/discussion-between-wundwin-born-and-neil-stockton).